# SQL Server data search with date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following columns:

```
Date
Skills,
Customer ID
```

I want to find out Date(x), Customers, Count of Customers in between Date(x) and Date(x)+6

Can somebody guide me how to make this query, or can I create this function in SQL Server?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't include the effort that you've made, or where you're having trouble with it. Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After that, [start here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

*(take care, can be bad syntax, because i "work" only with oracle. But I think that it should work)*

```
select date, customer_id, COUNT(*) 
from your_table --add your table
where date between getdate() and DATEADD(day, 6, getdate()) 
 -- between current database system date and +6 day
group by date, customer id
order by COUNT (*) desc --  if you want, you can order your result - ASC||DESC
```

Comment: Brother, You didn't get my point, your query is providing me daily customers for the same day, however, I am looking for Day 1 customers and the counts of repetition in next 6 days

Answer (score 0):

If you have data on each date, then perhaps this is what you want:

```
select date, count(*),
       sum(count(*)) over (order by date rows between 6 preceding and current row) as week_count
from t
group by date;
```

Comment: Dear I didn't ask for Week data and there is no date range also